# How to get buildable android app out of AOSP source

Tags: android, android-source

I try to make a own Dialer-App, to get some basic functions to work I try to get the original Dailer from the AndroidOpenSourceProject up to running. I pulled the code from [AOPS Dialer master](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/refs/heads/master) and open it in Android Studio. It told me it detects 103 Manifest files but the project could not build.

As I understand this projects need to be builded into a ROM and not to be builded with the SDK. Is there anyway how I can get this project to be builded with Android Studio and run it on a device/emulator?

Comment: You would need to remove everything from the app that depends upon APIs that are not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Thank you! it there any good way how i could detect it?

Comment: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. Import the code into an Android Studio project, then start fixing build errors. That may take you quite some time and may not leave much of an app left.